# How can I return dynamic content using wiremock json templates?

Tags: wiremock

I want to return a response using wiremock where the content is based on the supplied request.  Specifically I want to return a value for 'stake' that is 1000 * a value.

I have a response template that works fine for static data.  I can even have a dynamic value for the stake as follows:

```
{
  "stake": {{request.path.1}}
}
```

But I cannot work out how to multiply that value by 1000.  I know this is using handlebars, but I cannot locate the handlebars helper I need.

Comment: As you may have noticed this is not supported out of the box. Are you running WireMock using the standalone jar, or are you incorporating it into a java application?

Comment: Incorporating it into a java application.  So maybe I need to write my own customer handlebars helper then.

Comment: Yep. I think so too.